# How can I search ods file for keywords and show entire row, not just the cell that contains keyword?

Tags: search, grep, ods

I have an .ods file. I need to search said file for keyword and need the result to reflect the entire row, not just the cell containing the keyword.
Here is the file in question:

```
RO     JOB  REPAIR          TIME
224576   1  DASH HARNESS    26.3
224577   5  APIM FLASH      1.5
224578   3  SUNROOF         11.9
224579   9  OIL CHANGE      0.3
```

I found a script called odfgrep [here](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2018/213/Tutorials-odfgrep/(offset)/3) that works well, but the results returned are only the cell containing the keyword:

```
./odfgrep DASH FEB23.ods
DASH HARNESS
```

What I would like to see, is the entire row, preferably with the header:

```
./odfgrep DASH FEB23.ods
RO     JOB  REPAIR          TIME
224576   1  DASH HARNESS    26.3
```

Side note, I intend to incorporate this with a zentity script.
I've had issues in the past with people not understanding my question. If this is not clear enough, please do not close, give me a chance to fix it, and please offer some pointers as to where it is unclear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below adaptation of odfgrep shows the full line, separating cells with comma (in your example you may grep on "\(REPAIR\|DASH\)" then you may pipe to sed or other to have a different separator)

```
#!/bin/bash
### grep Libreoffice files (temporarily converted to text)
### adapted for LibreOffice from https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2018/213/Tutorials-odfgrep/(offset)/3
### note: like original odfgrep, can only be used in a directory in which one can create (and delete) files (and a subdir)

OPTIONS=$@
ODFOPTIONS=`echo $@ | sed -e 's/\.\(odt\|odp\|ods\)\b/\.\1\.odfgrep\.txt/g'`

### explicit initialization
FILES2REMOVE=""

### working subdir
WORKDIR=.odfgrep

### don't mess with it if pre-existing, let the user clean it up
if [ -d "$WORKDIR" ]
then
    echo $WORKDIR already exists
    exit 1
fi

### try creating it
if ! mkdir $WORKDIR
then
    echo $WORKDIR cannot be created
    exit 1
fi


for FF in $OPTIONS
do
    if [ -f "$FF" ]
    then
         case "$FF" in
             *.odt|*.odp|*.ods)
          ### odt2txt not needed any more, but extension cannot be specified, let's put the result in our subdir
                  libreoffice --convert-to txt $FF --outdir $WORKDIR
          FFBASE=`echo $FF | sed -e 's/\.od[pst]//'`
          ### then move it to odfgrep expected filename with special extension
          mv $WORKDIR/$FFBASE.txt $FF.odfgrep.txt
                  FILES2REMOVE="$FILES2REMOVE $FF.odfgrep.txt"
                  ;;
             *) # non-ODF file found, nothing to do
                  ;;
         esac
    fi
done

### redirection of error output for case of non-existing file
grep $ODFOPTIONS 2>&1 | sed -e 's/\.odfgrep\.txt//'

### extraneous brackets and slashes removed
if [ -n "$FILES2REMOVE" ]
then
    rm $FILES2REMOVE
fi

### finally, remove the empty working subdir
rmdir $WORKDIR

exit
```

Comment: Not usre if I'm using your example correctly, but I tired it with the exmaple command I used in op and it doesn't work.

---Error: no export filter for /home/thomas/Desktop/ODF-CSV/.odfgrep/FEB23.txt found, aborting.
Error: no export filter
mv: cannot stat '.odfgrep/FEB23.txt': No such file or directory
grep: FEB23.ods: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'FEB23.ods.odfgrep.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry for the sloppiness of my comment, but I was trying to figure out display the errors as code and this site only allows you 5 minuted to edit a comments. Trial and error made that time expire. None-the-less, I used "./odfgrep DASH FEB23.ods" and got the above error

Comment: i have only tested this script with LibreOffice 7.5, do you have or can you upgrade to this version? (sorry for the late answer)

Comment: updaqted to LibreOffice 7.5.2 but still the same errors. I'm using ./odfgrep2 "\(REPAIR\|DASH\)" FEB23.ods and have tried several variations, but all end in the same error.

Comment: very strange, it works for me:
`odfgrep "\(REPAIR\|DASH\)" FEB23.ods
RO,JOB,REPAIR,TIME
224576,1,DASH HARNESS,26.3`

(note that backslash is also needed for the parentheses)

Can you check whether this creates a text file:
`libreoffice --convert-to txt FEB23.ods`

Comment: nope: 'Error: no export filter for /home/thomas/Desktop/ODF-CSV/FEB23.txt found, aborting.
Error: no export filter'

Comment: then can you install LibreOffice filters?

Comment: I have filters options but have no clue how to use them. I'm doing some research and testing now though.